# Where are the settings of a preferences screen stored?

Tags: android, settings, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I know this question is a little stupid but I cannot find where the settings of my preferences screen are stored.

I am using shared preferences this file is located at `/data/data/my.package.name/shared_prefs/common.xml`. However when I change something the changes are stored. I even implemented custom controls which can store their information so far. But however I cannot figure out where the settings are stored. `/data/data/my.package.name/` is only one xml file which does not contain any related information. I also checked the virtual directories for multi user devices with no luck.

Here is my xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/my.package.name"
    android:persistent="true" >

    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_basics_group" >
        <EditTextPreference
            android:key="nickname"
            android:persistent="true"
            android:positiveButtonText="@string/setting_change_name"
            android:title="@string/settings_username" />
        <my.package.name.controls.EmailPreference
            android:key="mail"
            android:title="@string/settings_email"
            custom:domains="@array/known_email_domains" />
        <Preference
            android:summary="Mars"
            android:title="@string/settings_current_location" />
        <my.package.name.controls.DatePreference
            android:key="birthday"
            android:title="@string/settings_birthday" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I would be really happy if somebody could explain me where these settings are stored.

Comment: Please explain what "However when I change something the changes are stored" - do you mean "However when I change something the changes are ___not___ stored ___there___"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For older Android versions including Jelly Bean (API 16) and older the answer of [Dalmas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17292500/995926) is correct. So feel free to upvote that answer.

Beginning with [Jelly Bean MR1](http://developer.android.com/about/versions/jelly-bean.html) (API 17) there are new rules about path due the multiuser support:

I figured out that the settings file is located in `/data/user/##/my.package.name/shared_prefs/my.package.name_preferences.xml` where `##` is my numeric user id.

For solving that path you need the `ApplicationContext` there you need to reflect `mLoadedAPK` and there `mDataDir`. For now I'm happy with that I could get the path from the debugger. Sorry to everyone who wants a ready to use code snippet, you have to do that yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The app preferences are stored in the default shared preferences that you can retrieve with [`PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceManager.html#getDefaultSharedPreferences%28android.content.Context%29).

The XML file itself is located at `/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME/shared_prefs/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_preferences.xml`

Comment: That is really helpful to know that I can access the settings in this way, but there is no such file. That **is** my problem. I can also eliminate that this settings are only in the memory. Even if I crash or shutdown my app this settings are stored.

Comment: What is your android version?

Comment: I'm trying that on a 4.2.2 device (API 17). But on another API 10 device with (2.3.5) the file is there. Strange.

Comment: I figgered out that the file is located in `/data/user/##/my.package.name/shared_prefs/my.package.name_preferences.xml` where `##` is my numeric user id. I cannot read this file from console but this mistery is sloved for me. For sloving that path you need the `ApplicationContext` there you need to reflect `mLoadedAPK` and there `mDataDir`.